# Sify broadband dialer client fail to install

Tags: unity, kubuntu, launchpad, broadband, dhclient

A few days ago I tried to migrate directly towards ubuntu 11.04,but find it difficult,because my internet connection doesn't works as it depends on sify dialer login GUI program provided on windows.

So, I tried all googling about that dialer client for ubuntu, I found this:

> client developer site:  http://sites.google.com/site/sifydialer/

And

> its Launchpad repository: https://launchpad.net/connectplus

but as I don't know how to help this developer of connect plus for faster delivery of stable client, I request anyone here, who has done something like that before please help him accomplish that faster, as its opensource client.

OR provide me another way out from such situation .

What I tried already:

- I tried connect-plus dialer installation,it never starts and I tried sify dialer of windows on ubuntu ,using wine, I installed it, but can't find where its gone in Ubuntu 11.04, so stuck there.
- And I can't operate in terminal, as I'm newbie, don't know any commands.

Comment: it never starts and I tried sify dialer of windows on ubuntu ,using wine,I installed it,but can't find where its gone in Ubuntu 11.04,so stucked their.

Comment: I'm new to ubuntu,that's why I'm trying to search all GUI tools for it.,so what can I do in terminal

Comment: ok - understand.  Dont use the windows version of Sify - it will never work.  You've downloaded the v0.2 .deb file from the website.  You've installed the .deb file by double clicking the .deb file? Then open the dash (top left icon on the desktop) and search for connect.  Click on the icon.  What happens?

Comment: it doesn't respond, and throws me back on desktop by closing top left dashboard.

Comment: open your dash and search for terminal.  Now type the following - copy and paste the output into your question.  `mono /usr/bin/connectplus/ConnectPlus.exe`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved above Sify problem i ubuntu 11.04 linux like this:

1. downloading sify client from:
   https://sites.google.com/site/sifydialer/download
2. Before Installation,I need following things to be installed first:

   > Java Runtime environment  , 
   >   "libmono-system-data2.0-cil"  via synaptic package manager
3. Then finally Install,it should probably give No error, although I    f it gives any error,then please refer the below link of Issue    resolution page of this client:    https://sites.google.com/site/sifydialer/troubleshoot

This issue has been resolved in the new package "connectplus_0.2-natty_all.deb" which can be download from "https://sites.google.com/site/sifydialer/download"